# Fabric js, how to save data

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

How to save added object in canvas via jquery? with all attributes

```
{
   translate: '';
   x: '';
   y: ''; 
   style: ''; 
   width: ''; 
   height: ''; 
   xlink href: ''; 
   preserveAspectRatio: '';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery will not help you to do this.

When you start to use fabric you can call `.toObject()` on either the whole fabric canvas object to get the full state of the fabric canvas, or you can call `.toObject()` on any one fabric object to just get the data from that object.

If you have the data for a whole canvas and want to replace an existing canvas or start new one you can use the `.loadFromJSON(yourDataHere)` on the fabric canvas object.

If you just have data for a single object you would like to add to an existing canvas you can add it with the `fabric.util.enlivenObjects(arrayOfObjectData, callbackFunction)` which wants an array of the data you go from each object to be passed in followed by a callback function which will be passed the recreated objects that you can then add to any fabric canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `canvas.toJson` to serialize canvas values. You could then save them somewhere.

```
var json = canvas.toJSON();
alert(JSON.stringify(json));
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```